# SQLite : How to combine subquery results

Tags: sqlite

I have a table like this

```
    id  |   inventory_id    |   serial_type |   serial
------------------------------------------------------
    38  |       5892        |       1       |   9502
    39  |       5895        |       1       |   i95054-1
    40  |       5895        |       2       |   m95054-1
    41  |       5895        |       1       |   i95054-2
    42  |       5895        |       2       |   m95054-2
    43  |       5895        |       1       |   i95054-3
    44  |       5895        |       2       |   m95054-3
    45  |       5895        |       1       |   i95054-4
    46  |       5895        |       2       |   m95054-4
```

I have 2 subqueries from same table like

```
SELECT inventory_id, serial as type_one_serial
FROM serials
WHERE serial_type = 1
AND inventory_id = 5895
```

and another

```
SELECT inventory_id, serial as type_two_serial
FROM serials
WHERE serial_type = 2
AND inventory_id = 5895
```

How I can combine these to get a result like

```
inventory_id | type_one_serial | type_two_serial
------------------------------------------------
5895         |  i95054-1       |    m95054-1
5895         |  i95054-2       |    m95054-2
5895         |  i95054-3       |    m95054-3
5895         |  i95054-4       |    m95054-4
```

**EDIT :**
I have modified the source table to iclude another column `sl`

```
    sl  |   id  |   inventory_id    |   serial_type |   serial
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
    0   |   38  |       5892        |       1       |   9502
    0   |   39  |       5895        |       1       |   i95054-1
    0   |   40  |       5895        |       2       |   m95054-1
    1   |   41  |       5895        |       1       |   i95054-2
    1   |   42  |       5895        |       2       |   m95054-2
    2   |   43  |       5895        |       1       |   i95054-3
    2   |   44  |       5895        |       2       |   m95054-3
    3   |   45  |       5895        |       1       |   i95054-4
    3   |   46  |       5895        |       2       |   m95054-4
```

Comment: You should show us the general format of the `serial` column, assuming you would want to be able to handle any `inventory_id`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : The `serial` column is user defined and is alphanumeric

Comment: I meant the general formst if known.  In any case, I gave you a query below which should work at least for the sample data you showed us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a pivot query:

```
SELECT inventory_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN serial_type = 1 THEN 'i' || SUBSTR(serial, 2) END) AS type_one_serial,
       MAX(CASE WHEN serial_type = 2 THEN 'm' || SUBSTR(serial, 2) END) AS type_two_serial
FROM serials
WHERE serial_type IN (1, 2) AND      -- the WHERE clause may be optional
      inventory_id = 5895            -- depending on what you want
GROUP BY inventory_id,
         SUBSTR(serial, 2)
```

**Update:**

Taking the new `sl` column into account, we can use this to discriminate between the two types of serials for a given `inventory_id`.  In this case, we could write the following query:

```
SELECT inventory_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN serial_type = 1 THEN serial END) AS type_one_serial,
       MAX(CASE WHEN serial_type = 2 THEN serial END) AS type_two_serial
FROM serials
GROUP BY inventory_id,
         sl
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your time! But I think, it is not the exact code I am looking for. As the `serial` column is user defined, I cannot do a `SUBSTR`.

Comment: If you want to pivot, we need to know the structure of the `serial` column.  Surely you have some kind of requirements?

Comment: `serial` is taken from a user input text field, which user can input any alpha-numeric character set say upto a length of 50. The above data is just some test data, in reality, it will be any random characters. Hope I have answered your question.

Comment: There needs to be some way to group together matching pairs of `serial` values.  In the absence of this, I'm not sure a general query can be given here.

Comment: What if I add another column `sl` (please see the edit in the question) ?

Comment: I have updated my question taking the change into account.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen ! Your answer yields what I wanted. I learned a bit from this post. Could you please look into the modification I have done and advice (below).

Answer (score 0):

@Tim Biegeleisen 's edited answer worked perfectly for me. I have done few modifications based on that. Not sure it will make any improvement, just posting here for reference :

`SELECT inventory_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN serial_type = 1 THEN serial END) AS type_one_serial, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN serial_type = 2 THEN serial END) AS type_two_serial 
FROM serials 
WHERE inventory_id = 5895 
GROUP BY sl`

Comment: This is acceptable provided you only want to look at one `inventory_id`.  My answer would cover the entire table.

Comment: One edit: You can't select the `inventory_id` now because it doesn't appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.  So I selected it as a constant text instead.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen! My actual code is bit different (Edited it again) :)

Comment: I don't like your recent edit.  You _can't_ (or at least should not) select the `inventory_id` if it doesn't appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.  This is why I selected static text, to get around this problem.  Or, just go with my answer above.